# How to use unity "JobSystem" Without main thread , And not freeze?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use that load some in backgound , But Jobsystem probably use the main thread , So how to do use jobsystem  Wituhot Freezes , is it impossible ?? 
Or I just use C# Thread?? Dont Use JobSystem ??

```
struct SleepJob : IJobParallelFor
{
    public void Execute(int index)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("[SleepJob.Execute] Thread Id {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
}
struct SleepJob2 : IJobParallelFor
{
    public void Execute(int index)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("[SleepJob2.Execute] Thread Id {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
}
[ContextMenu("JobSleep")]
public void JobSleep()
{
    Debug.LogFormat("[JobSleep.Execute] Thread Id {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    SleepJob job = new SleepJob() { };
    SleepJob2 job2 = new SleepJob2() { };
    JobHandle jh = job.Schedule(100, 64);
    JobHandle jh2 = job2.Schedule(100, 64, jh);
    JobHandle.ScheduleBatchedJobs();
    jh2.Complete(); // freezes

    Debug.LogFormat("[JobSleep.Execute] jh.Complete();");
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) ?

Comment: @remy_rm Yes , But When Use corotines in main thread , 
It also let FPS be a little slower

Comment: @remy_rm Coroutines run in the main thread.

Comment: What exactly is the background task you want to do? Maybe a simple `Thread` would be enough?

Comment: @derHugo I Want to Decode something & save file in backgroud ,
I tried C# thread it worked , But I looked jobsystem , It use unity own thread , maybe jobsystem is better so I trying found the best solution 0.0

Comment: I don't know the Jobsystem so can't help with that. But it sounds like a simple `Thread` or using [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) might also do it .. it would help if you added the code that actually is supposed to be executed in background

Comment: Note that [`Complete`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Jobs.JobHandle.Complete.html) makes your execution freeze because: "The JobSystem automatically prioritizes the job and any of its dependencies to run first in the queue, then attempts to execute the job itself **on the thread which calls the Complete function**."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that [`Complete`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Jobs.JobHandle.Complete.html) makes your execution freeze because:

> The JobSystem automatically prioritizes the job and any of its dependencies to run first in the queue, then attempts to execute the job itself **on the thread which calls the Complete function**.

I think this is not the method you want to use.

Rather try waiting for the Job to complete in a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like e.g.

```
[ContextMenu("JobSleep")]
public void JobSleep()
{
    Debug.LogFormat("[JobSleep.Execute] Thread Id {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    SleepJob job = new SleepJob() { };
    SleepJob2 job2 = new SleepJob2() { };
    JobHandle jh = job.Schedule(100, 64);
    JobHandle jh2 = job2.Schedule(100, 64, jh);
    JobHandle.ScheduleBatchedJobs();

    StartCoroutine(WaitFor(jh2));
}

IEnumerator WaiFor(JobHandle job)
{
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => job.IsComplete);

    Debug.LogFormat("[JobSleep.Execute] job IsComplete");
}
```

---

Unfortunately you didn't add the code you actually want to be executed in background.

In general maybe simply using a [`Thread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread) or [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) might already solve your problem.

e.g. with a `Thread`

```
// for sending back responses to the main thread
private ConcurrentQueue<Action> callbacks = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>;

// work the callbacks in the main thread
private void Update()
{
    while(callbacks.Count > 0)
    {
        Action callback;
        if(callbacks.TryDequeue(out callback)) callback?.Invoke();
    }
}

// optional callback on success
public void StartBackgroundTask(Action onSuccess = null)
{
    var thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(TheTaskThatTakesAWhile);
    // pass in parameters here
    thread.Start(onSuccess);
}

// Will be running in a background thread
private void TheTaskThatTakesAWhile(Action onSuccess)
{
    // hand this back to the main thread
    callbacks.Enqueue(() => Debug.Log("Long task started ..."));

    // TODO whatever takes so long

    // Note btw that sleep is in milliseconds!
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    hand this back to the mainthread
    callbacks.Enqueue(() => 
    {
        Debug.Log("Long task started ..."));

        onSuccess?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

e.g. using `async` (which internally also runs in a Thread)

```
private async Task TheTaskThatTakesAWhile()
{
    // do whatever takes long here
}

// usually you should avoid having async void
// but when including an Action as callback this is fine
public async void StartBackgroundTask(Action onSuccess = null)
{
    await TheTaskThatTakesAWhile();

    onSuccess?.Invoke();
}
```

Both you could call like e.g.

```
StartBackgroundTask(() => {
    // what should happen when done?

    Debug.Log("I'm done!");
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot , It a perfect solution !!

Answer (score 1):

Make JobHandle jh2 global variable. Check JobHandle.isComplete in Update method or in Coroutine